# Yeoman for Angular, then "grunt serve" won't start

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

This is the first time I use yeoman to setup the scaffolding for an AngularJS app, and I have to admit I am likely new to the nodeJS, grunt and bower world.

So, here's what I've done so far:

- I made sure yeoman, grunt-cli and the angular-generator packages are installed

  ```
  npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower
  npm install -g generator-angular
  ```
- Generated my app

  ```
  yo angular
  ```

  I also tried:

  ```
  yo angular --min-safe
  ```

So far, al seems good. Between the options given, I choose the Twitter Bootstrap one, no angular dependencies, and to overwrite my local .gitignore file.

After all that, I try to run my app:

```
grunt serve
```

At this point, grunt complains that it is not locally installed into the project, so I run:

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
```

No again, trying to run the app:

```
grunt serve
```

And this is where I get blocked:

```
C:\Projects\what-now>grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

Running "copy:styles" (copy) task

Done, without errors.
    Warning:
    C:\Projects\what-now\node_modules\grunt-contrib-compass\node_modules\tmp\lib\tmp.js:261
      throw err;
            ^
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'stdout' of undefined
        at compile (C:\Projects\what-now\node_modules\grunt-contrib-compass\tasks\compass.js:37:10)
        at C:\Projects\what-now\node_modules\grunt-contrib-compass\tasks\compass.js:68:7
        at C:\Projects\what-now\node_modules\grunt-contrib-compass\tasks\lib\compass.js:121:11
        at _fileCreated (C:\Projects\what-now\node_modules\grunt-contrib-compass\node_modules\tmp\lib\tmp.js:172:7)
        at C:\Projects\what-now\node_modules\grunt-google-cdn\node_modules\bower\node_modules\rimraf\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:53:5
        at C:\Projects\what-now\node_modules\grunt-google-cdn\node_modules\bower\node_modules\rimraf\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:62:5
        at OpenReq.Req.done (C:\Projects\what-now\node_modules\grunt-google-cdn\node_modules\bower\node_modules\fstream\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:142:5)
        at OpenReq.done (C:\Projects\what-now\node_modules\grunt-google-cdn\node_modules\bower\node_modules\fstream\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:64:22)
        //... stack trace continues ...
```

Looking at the code that blows up in compass' compile method, what I find is the following:

```
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
```

This makes me think that `child` is undefined for some reason, and this variable comes from a call to `grunt.util.spawn`. This is where I am at a loss.

Am I missing any dependency? Am I missing any configuration?

*Info:*

- OS: Windows 8 x64
- node: v0.10.22

Comment: I am so glad you put the full text of the error in your question. Saved me quite a bit of trouble after I ingeniously decided to break my ruby configuration.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**sighs**, sorry.

All it took me is to write this question to then figure out I needed to have installed Ruby and the compass gem. Now it makes sense: the process for compiling would not spawn up.

After installing Ruby, run:

```
gem install compass
```

And you should be good to go.

**EDIT:** After you install Ruby, you need to make sure that the ruby runtime files' path is added to your PATH variable. (Thanks JagWire!)

Comment: I would also go so far as to say that you need your ruby installation's bin folder path appended to the global path environment variable.

Comment: Is it just me, or does anybody else wonder why I should need to install ruby to use yeoman to set up a angular or ember project?

Comment: @fool4jesus It's because Compass is written in Ruby. Would be nice if everything just ran with nodejs. I just wish there was a more helpful error message!

Comment: @ScottCornwell Yeah, I figured that was the case. It just seems odd - and as you say the error message could definitely do with improvement. :-)

Comment: add instructions to add the `gem` command e.g. `sudo apt-get install ruby` & `sudo apt-get install rubygems-integration`

Comment: @JossefHarush The original question had the context of a Windows environment, which is just about downloading and executing an installer -- do you think it's useful to specify how to install ruby since there are several ways to go about it?

Comment: Wait... why is Ruby / rubygems needed for yeoman / angular scaffolding? compass does... what?

Answer (score 4):

On windows i had a few instalations of ruby:

```
    C:\ruby187
```

and

```
    C:\Ruby200-x64
```

install compass in both places, using:

```
    gem install compass
```

this resolve my issue on windows 8 64bit

Answer (score 2):

Following the same procedure for Ember, running grunt. Received the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'stdout' of undefined." Did gem install compass (ruby had already been installed on my windows 7 64 bit) even though compass was supposed to be installed earlier and this worked. Ran grunt and grunt serve with no problems.